# nptdms channel_data doesn't load the data I see in the file, why?

Tags: python, labview

I have an issue with reading tdms files with nptdms module, I seem to use it correctly looking at the examples but the output differs from expected. Here is my code:

```
tdms_file = TdmsFile("path_to_file\file.tdms")
channel0 = tdms_file.object("FBdata", "FBchannel0")
data0 = channel0.data
print data0[0]
```

I can preview the values in channel0 in Excel and the elements of the data0 array and the values in the column FBchannel0 are completely different

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please give an excerpt of the file to see what you are talking about and explain what completely different means? Does one method give you the correct numbers and the other one tiny leprechauns? we can't guess this!

Comment: unfortunately no tiny leprechauns...In the meantime I solved the issue. Apparently the tdms files were produced with a " , " delimiter and this was causing the issue. Once the settings in LabView were changed to specify " . " as the delimiter, the produced files could be correctly read with the npTDMS Python module.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I solved the issue. Apparently the tdms files were produced with a " , " delimiter and this was causing the issue. Once the settings in LabView were changed to specify " . " as the delimiter, the produced files could be correctly read with the npTDMS Python module.